# mystery of the missing transform in rviz

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why is there not a line from camera_frame to object_position

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204363/mystery-of-the-missing-transform-in-rviz/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is related to a configuration file that does not match my target marker specs.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2015-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the *Show Arrows* checkbox checked for the *TF* display in RViz?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-06**:
yes....i turned off the other frames to show  only the camera_frame and object_position is shown. Note the camera_frame would not show if the show arrows was off.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-06**:
I'm a little confused: I think only *Show Axes* off would not show the camera frame (only the name)? Turning *Show Arrows* off should just remove the 'lines' between the frames.

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-03-06**:
yes, you are right. However I do have the show arrows set to on in the example.